# Using SSH with xagrs. Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Tags: ssh, xargs

have been trying to do something like `cat file | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ssh`  and it's possible to login (prompted for a password but displayed **Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal**.). if I pass the **-tt** argument to ssh it will give me a shell but it's just froze (unable to write anything to the shell). my questing is simply if it's possible to pass arguments to ssh using xargs or pipe? (such that ssh's stdin or argument is stdout of another command NOT the shell)?

I know it's possible to do something like `` ssh `cat somefile` `` assuming that *somefile* contains something like username@server, at the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you don't use password authentication, but one of the other forms of authentication SSH provides:

- Host-based authentication, or more preferrably
- Public key authentication.

If both don't work for you, `ssh-askpass` or an alternative with setting the environment variable SSH_ASKPASS could be an option. Still I would not recommend that as you seem to be reading the passwords from a cleartext file now and probably would keep that.

Comment: I was wondering more about using ssh along with other commands such as  ``` echo "username@server | xargs ssh ```, and how to get a working terminal after login using such method.  not about authentication methods.

Comment: But your questions exactly shows that you want to use the authentication method "keyboard interactive" and SSH is really picky that it is _interactive_, so I thought if you are trying to execute commands from a file on a specific server, it might help to switch the authentication method to something non-interactive. It also would help if you want to have a shortcut for interactively logging in by SSH - you can define configurations for each host with a shortcut, that includes hostname, username and authentication. (E.g. `ssh a` could effectivly log you in as with `ssh myuser@xa.host.com`)